# Both UITableViewDataSource and HomeModel doesnt conform to ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Even though i looked at other threads containing the same question, i have no clue what so ever, why it says this.

My code looks like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, HomeModelProtocal {

@IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!



var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
var selectedLocation : Parsexml = Parsexml()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //set delegates and initialize homeModel

    self.listTableView.delegate = self
    self.listTableView.dataSource = self

    let homeModel = HomeModel()
    homeModel.delegate = self
    homeModel.downloadItems()

    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of feed items
        return feedItems.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

        let cellIdentifier: String = "BasicCell"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!

        let item: Parsexml = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! Parsexml

        myCell.textLabel!.text = item.title

        return myCell
    }
```

I have tried to use the suggested code, but no luck.

Comment: You are mixing up Swift 2 and Swift 3 code. What version do you use? It would be helpful at least to mention the version in the question or to set the right tag.

Comment: oh, i use swift 3 of cause :-) - but really, im using a tutorial on google. So when it doesnt suggest me changing, im rarely spotting it

Comment: Look for tutorials which match your Swift version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift 3

`numberOfRowsInSection` is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

and `cellForRowAt indexPath` is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

You can easily find out yourself: Comment out a whole method and retype the first letters `tableV` and see what code completion suggests.

Even in Swift 2 the signature of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is wrong. All parameters are non-optional values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do still however encounter the error 

Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'

Comment: In the Issue Navigator (⌘4) click on the triangle next to the error. It indicates which method is missing. Did you copy and paste the methods properly? Consider the underscores and `IndexPath` rather than `NSIndexPath`

Comment: hmm it says "do you want to add a stub" in both tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)' with type '(UITableView, Int) -> Int'

And

tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)' with type '(UITableView, IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell'

What does it mean?

Comment: I have no idea. The signatures of both methods in the answer are correct.